# Moving a div down

Tags: html, css

I am working a `website`, but having the problem that I cant move the navigation bar down in the header. Really worried about it.

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2QLz4/

The target is to make it look like this in the header:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2ijroj58vey2rf/target.png

Comment: include your code here

Comment: Being fast is also a very useful technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to worry about.

Add this:

```
ul#nav, ul#nav ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 40px 20px 0 0;
}
```

See this demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/2QLz4/1**/

Comment: It's so funny! In the jsfiddle the navigation is moving but when I copied the code to notepad++ it's stuck and not moving.

Comment: Interesting, but I see you solved it by using the code. I am glad!

Answer (score 2):

Update your css. [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eA8Uk/)

```
ul#nav, ul#nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin:40px 20px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are sevel ways to do this but a simple way to do this is by using the code below:

```
ul#nav, ul#nav ul{
    list-style: outside none;
    margin: 40px 20px 0 0;
}
```

This should salve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just Make change In header class in ul#nav.
Add margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px; in ul#nav class.

```
ul#nav, ul#nav .subs {
margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```